# How can i make temporary object in Sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, mysql, object, sequelize.js, temporary

Hello guys im creating some program, when program loaded it needs to load all items from database and assign to them gameobject, temporary objects in game that are not saved in database
Photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5h0T.png
And i console.log(this), that object and my game object is in there, but later it's not.
when i try Instance.object it's undefined, he's not assigned.

Soo how can i make this works, or maybe is there any method to define object in model that is not supposed to be saved ? Thank you in advance !

MODEL (i added it as VIRTUAL, still nothing)

```
frp.Items = frp.Database.define('Item', {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
      Item: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      Quantity: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 1 },
      Entity: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: -1 },
      Owner: { type: DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: 0 },
      isWeapon: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, defaultValue: false },
      Ammo: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
      Last_Owner: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
      Position: {
         type: DataTypes.TEXT, defaultValue: null,
         get: function () { return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('Position')); },
         set: function (value) { this.setDataValue('Position', JSON.stringify(value)); }
      },
      Rotation: {
         type: DataTypes.TEXT, defaultValue: null,
         get: function () { return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('Rotation')); },
         set: function (value) { this.setDataValue('Rotation', JSON.stringify(value)); }
      },
      Dimension: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
      GameObject: { 
         type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
         set: function (x) { 
            this.setDataValue('GameObject', x);
         },
         
      }
   }, 
   {
      timestamps: true,
      underscrored: true,
      createdAt: "Created_Date",
      updatedAt: "Update_Date",
   }
);
```

FUNCTION

```
frp.Items.prototype.Refresh = function () {
   if (this.Entity == ItemEntities.Ground) {
      const Position = this.Position;
      const Rotation = this.Rotation;
      console.log(Position);
      this.GameObject = mp.objects.new(ItemRegistry[this.Item].hash, new mp.Vector3(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z), {
         rotation: new mp.Vector3(Rotation.x, Rotation.y, Rotation.z),
         alpha: 255,
         dimension: this.Dimension
      });
      this.GameObject.Item = this.id;

      console.log('Turilo game object ' + this.GameObject.Item);
   
   } else {
      if (this.GameObject) {
         this.GameObject.destroy();
      }
   }
};
```

LOADING

```
(async () => {

   frp.Items.sync();

   const Items = await frp.Items.findAll();
   Items.forEach((Item) => {
      Item.Refresh();
   });

   setTimeout(async () => {
      const objs = await frp.Items.findAll();
      objs.forEach((obj) => { 
         console.log(obj.GameObject) // RETURN UNDEFINED
      })
   }, 5000);


   frp.Main.Terminal(3, Items.length + ' Items Loaded !');
})();
```

Comment: Please post the code examples as text. You can format it with ```

Comment: There's no reason for a property to disappear. There must be some code changing it but that will probably need some more code to debug, unless its available on a site?

Comment: i pasted the code